# Nested UNPACKs in GHC

Tags: optimization, haskell, data-structures, ghc

I often gather multiple values in tuples, since I consider tuples to be the natural type for this. However, tuples are not strict. So consider

```
data A

data B =
    B !A

data C =
    C !(B, B)

data D =
    D !B !B
```

With `-funbox-strict-fields` and optimization, UNPACKs are nested. Will the tuple in `C` be unpacked into `C A A` as with `D`, or just `C B B`? Here is a reference in GHC-doc: [7.16. Pragmas](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/pragmas.html#unpack-pragma).

(are non-empty tuples *types*? type-constructors?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider:

```
data B = B !Int

data C = C !(B, B)

data D = D !B !B

b0 = B 7
b1 = B 4

c = C (b0, b1)

d = D b0 b1
```

where

```
data (,) a b = (a,b)
```

GHC will happily erase nested, strict constructors `(!B)`, and it will make C strict in its first field, optimizing to:

```
b0 = B 7
b1 = B 4

c = C b0 b1

d = D 7 4
```

However, importantly, the fields of `(,)` itself are not strict -- so GHC can't unpack them. Furthermore, they're polymorphic, so it can't unpack them even if they are strict.

A work around for the first part is to use strict tuples. The workaround for the second part is to use [self-specializing tuples](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/adaptive-containers/0.3/doc/html/Data-Adaptive-Tuple.html) (e.g. type families that specialize tuples).

---

Note that using tuples for syntax in this style incurs overhead -- they introduce a level of indirection that must be optimized away. As such, it is somewhat unidiomatic.

Comment: I fixed an error in my question: data B should be data B = B !A. So in C I should instead use my own specialized type, which has strict fields, instead of a tuple? I hoped that GHC could continue to unpack after finding a tuple, so I don't need to write a lot of specialized datatypes for each field. (But, since I gather values in tuples, I have probably some abstract idea of the set of values, so then I should probably use a specialized version anyway...)

Comment: It would if tuples weren't polymorphic. I've written about this problem previously: http://donsbot.wordpress.com/2009/10/11/self-optimizing-data-structures-using-types-to-make-lists-faster/

Comment: As I see from the examples in GHC-doc, a pair used as a strict field in a datatype will be flattened.